# How to find all numbers in document and style them?

Tags: javascript, regex, colors, numbers

I'm currently working on a website (personal) where I'm using JavaScript to find all numbers in my .html file (actually just in the `#wrapper` div). I want them all to be colored after.

My code looks as follows:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var str = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;

    var patt =/\d+/g;

    var res = str.match(patt);
    res = str.replace(patt, "<span class='em'>" + res + "</span>");

    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = res;

    window.alert(res)
};
```

The result with this code is that every number gets replaced by a String containing every single number in the marked area in a row, which is obviously not what I want.

I even tried it with a for-loop, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
var res = str.match(patt);
res = str.replace(patt, "<span class='em'>" + res + "</span>");
```

with

```
var res = str.replace(patt, "<span class='em'>$&</span>");
```

The special token `$&` tells `replace` to include the text that matched at that location in the replacement string. (If at some point you use capture groups in your regex, you can reference those as well with `$1` [for the first one], `$2` [for the second one], etc.)

Example:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML.replace(/\d+/g, '<span class="em">$&</span>');
```

```css
.em {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">This is the wrapper with numbers in it. Like 123. And 456.</div>
```

---

**Note**: If you have any event handlers on elements within the wrapper element, they'll be removed by replacing `innerHTML` (because the old elements are destroyed and replaced with new ones).

Comment: have been working with javascript for an year now, didnt know about `$&`, thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest amending your `replace()`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;

  var patt = /(\d+)/g;

  var res = str.replace(patt, "<span class='em'>$1</span>");

  document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = res;
};
```

```css
span.em {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><p>12345</p><p>12345</p></div>
```

The `"<span class='em'>$1</span>"` inserts the (first) matched portion of the regular expression into the replacement string.

```
res = str.replace(patt, "<span class='em'>$1</span>");
```

References:

- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: I guess you can get rid of `var res = str.match(patt);` which no longer has any purpose or effect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thanks! Note to self: pay more attention when deleting from code... :)